# How to exclude certain keys in a firebase database tree

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying only fetch to keys which are `children` of different date values. I've looked at the firebase api reference docs and they have `where` but can't seem to find where to use it. I want to exclude the key `date` and only display the rest. At the moment i get all but want to exclude `date`

```
2019-03-27
AB000002_AB0244
AB000002_AB0827
date
```

This is my firebase database

[image]

```
const fetchReminders =  ()=> {
    const ref  = db.ref("reminders");
    let dateTime = new Date();
    let currentDate = dateFormat(dateTime, "yyyy-mm-dd");
    ref
        .orderByChild('date')
        .endAt(currentDate)
        .once('value', (pSnapshot)=> {
            pSnapshot.forEach((theSnapshot)=> {
                console.log(theSnapshot.key);
                theSnapshot.forEach( (pNotificationSnapshot)=> {
                    console.log(pNotificationSnapshot.key);
                });
            });
    }).catch( (error)=> {
        console.log(error)
    })
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the database, since the `date` is already a parent node then there is no need to add a child node `date : 2019-03-10`, or if you have to add a `date` then you can add it under another `key`.

Your database should be created to make the query easy and possible.

More info here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible: with the Realtime Database

> Queries are deep by default: They always return the entire subtree.

as explained here https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/rtdb-vs-firestore#querying

Since you are querying for the immediate children of the `reminders` node, you will get the entire subtree, including the `AB000002_AB0244`, `AB000002_AB0827` nodes and their children, plus the `date` node.